# Why is PhpStorm ignoring DOMNodeList declaration within foreach loop?

Tags: php, phpstorm, undeclared-identifier

**Problem**

I can't quite replicate the issue since I am not certain when it suddenly began, however, I noticed suddenly that PhpStorm started having trouble referencing declared variables, especially those nested in a foreach loop.

```html
$articles = $doc->getElementsByTagName('article');
        foreach ($articles as $artcle) {
            $a_tags = $artcle->getElementsByTagName('a');
            ...
        }
}
```

`$articles` is an instance of `DOMNodeList` which implements `Traversable`. Originally `$artcle` would therefore be declared an instance of `DOMNode`, however, it only recently stopped recognizing this and shows up in the IDE as an undeclared variable, with `#getElementsByTagName('a')`, a public method that exists in `DOMNode`, unable to be referenced.

**What happens?**

Ignoring these errors in the IDE, the project runs perfectly fine locally (xampp webserver).

**What have I tried?**

I never messed with the configuration within my IDE, only have been spending time implementing a lot of new classes. I have already tried clearing my cache and restarting the application without any luck.

Comment: Are you able to share the full project/file that reproduces the problem? It's difficult to help here without having the objects used in the example at hand.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't, however, I have found that in other older projects that I have not touched, the same error occurs. Variables seem to not be declared an instance when they are assigned a value in the constructor. This definately appears to be an issue with the IDE. I have tried removing the .idea directory to remove any potential project configurations, but that hasn't resolved anything.

Comment: This certainly isn't the solution I was looking for and is a bit tedious but it looks like I can manually specify to the IDE how the variable is declared. 
`/* @var DOMNode $artcle*/`
This works but I feel the IDE should be able to automatically determine that looping through a DOMNodeList instance should declare each node from the list as a DOMNode instance and not see the designated variable as undeclared.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably something on an IDE side, but we can't say what exactly without an example that reproduces the issue. It would be great if you could submit a project that reproduces this to our tracker at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue